# how can i remove this error ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in D:\wamp64\www\complete_blog_php\admin\includes\post_functions.php on line 28

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, session

```
<?php 
// Post variables
$post_id = 0;
$isEditingPost = false;
$published = 0;
$title = "";
$post_slug = "";
$body = "";
$featured_image = "";
$post_topic = "";

/* - - - - - - - - - - 
-  Post functions
- - - - - - - - - - -*/
// get all posts from DB
function getAllPosts()
{
    global $conn;

    // Admin can view all posts
    // Author can only view their posts
    if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Admin") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    } elseif ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Author") {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $final_posts = array();
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $post['author'] = getPostAuthorById($post['user_id']);
        array_push($final_posts, $post);
    }
    return $final_posts;
}
// get the author/username of a post
function getPostAuthorById($user_id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=$user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        // return username
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['username'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code by pasting it and highlighting then using CTRL-K or the `{}`.

Comment: okay sir in a sec

Comment: However, enable error reporting and use `mysqli_error($conn)` which will help you debug it.

Comment: You could remove this `\`enter code here\`` from your post, then we could read it at least.  (there I fixed it up for you).  For the future the code goes between the backtics, but for a large block of code, put either 4 spaces or a tab before each line, which will make it a code block.

Comment: well sir seems am unable to ask till four days are over may I send you an e-mail:

Comment: @NjueChomba: The error message seems pretty clear.  On line 28 you're calling `mysqli_query()`.  You're giving it an empty (or at least invalid in such a way as to be interpreted as empty) query.  So, when this error happens, what is the value of the query you're sending it?  What do you expect it to be?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

If both of these conditions fail:

```
 if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Admin") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
} elseif ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Author") {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id";
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Then the `$sql` variable is undefined.  If you have to have them this way, then you can check if it's set and return a default value.

```
 if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Admin") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
} elseif ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Author") {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id";
}
if(!isset($sql)) return false; //or [] if you want the type to stay an array.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Or something like that, depending on your needs.

You could also return an error:

```
}else{
     return new WP_Error( 'restricted', __( "Not an Admin or Author", "my_textdomain" ) );
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error

Basically this `$_SESSION['user']['role']` is neither an `Admin` nor an `Author`.  one thing to note is string matches are case sensitive.

Comment: @NjueChomba - sure, glad I could help.  It's easy to miss because the `$sql` is filled in, in two places.  But if the condition fails then PHP doesn't see it.

Comment: i wish i could be a pro like you, am learning any tips? or do you teach php? am willing to learn

Comment: Well I been doing this sense 2009 (professionally) and I dabbled before that.

Comment: I honestly don't have time to teach or much else, but thanks for asking.  I only get on SO because I am waiting for the wife to finish dinner, and I don't feel like getting into working on a clients wordpress site when I have only a few minutes before I have to stop (and I have a full time job).  One of these days (if I get time) I will post some tutorials on my site, you can find the link to it in my profile, but I wouldn't hold my breath .... lol